# What does the command: var a, foo = "foo"; mean?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I came across this command:

```
var a, foo = "foo";
```

Is it two definition of variables, 
a and foo and initializing both of them to have "foo" as a value?

thanks

Comment: Try it out in your browser's console/the Node REPL.

Comment: It's two variables being declared, separated by a comma, the first one has no value, hence it's `undefined`, the second has the value `foo`. This is javascript 101, and some of the most basic constructs.

Comment: Thanks, i realized the meaning just before reading your answers.
I an a beginner so a lot is new for me. I did search it before posting but I guess I should have waited a bit longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a, foo = "foo";
```

Is the same as:

```
var a;
var foo = "foo";
```

It is declaring a variable named `a` with no value and a variable named `foo` with a value of foo.

I tend to write variables out the second way as it is more readable, but there are some people that prefer the first way as it is quicker.

Comment: thank u, i realized the meaning a moment before I saw your great answer